# Sending objects via sockets from Python to C/Fortran

Tags: python, c, sockets, fortran

The following codes are snippets of a larger software package. I want to understand how the code manages to send objects like numpy arrays, cells. What I wonder about is that the code does not seem to serialize the objects, but it does work. Why does it work?

Python client code (snippet):

```
class DriverSocket(socket.socket):

   def __init__(self, _socket_interface):
       super(DriverSocket,self).__init__(_sock=_socket_interface)


   def sendpos(self, pos, cell):
      """Sends the position and cell data to the driver.

      Args:
         pos: An array containing the atom positions.
         cell: A cell object giving the system box.

      Raises:
         InvalidStatus: Raised if the status is not Ready.
      """

      if (self.status & Status.Ready):
         try:
            self.sendall(Message("posdata"))
            self.sendall(cell.h)
            self.sendall(cell.ih)
            self.sendall(np.int32(len(pos)/3))
            self.sendall(pos)
         except:
            self.poll()
            return
      else:
         raise InvalidStatus("Status in sendpos was " + self.status)
```

Receiving code in C (snippet):

```
void open_socket_(int *psockfd, int* inet, int* port, char* host)
/* Opens a socket.

Note that fortran passes an extra argument for the string length, but this is
ignored here for C compatibility.

Args:
   psockfd: The id of the socket that will be created.
   inet: An integer that determines whether the socket will be an inet or unix
      domain socket. Gives unix if 0, inet otherwise.
   port: The port number for the socket to be created. Low numbers are often
      reserved for important channels, so use of numbers of 4 or more digits is
      recommended.
   host: The name of the host server.
*/

{
   int sockfd, portno, n;
   struct hostent *server;

   struct sockaddr * psock; int ssock;

   if (*inet>0)
   {  // creates an internet socket
      struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;      psock=(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr;     ssock=sizeof(serv_addr);
      sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
      if (sockfd < 0)  error("Error opening socket");

      server = gethostbyname(host);
      if (server == NULL)
      {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error opening socket: no such host %s \n", host);
         exit(-1);
      }

      bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
      serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
      serv_addr.sin_port = htons(*port);
      if (connect(sockfd, psock, ssock) < 0) error("Error opening socket: wrong host address, or broken connection");
   }
   else ...



void readbuffer_(int *psockfd, char *data, int* plen)
/* Reads from a socket.

Args:
   psockfd: The id of the socket that will be read from.
   data: The storage array for data read from the socket.
   plen: The length of the data in bytes.
*/

{
   int n, nr;
   int sockfd=*psockfd;
   int len=*plen;

   n = nr = read(sockfd,data,len);

   while (nr>0 && n<len )
   {  nr=read(sockfd,&data[n],len-n); n+=nr; }

   if (n == 0) error("Error reading from socket: server has quit or connection broke");
}
```

And then there is Fortran code which used the C-socket code

```
CALL open_socket(socket, inet, port, host)
...
CALL readbuffer(socket, msgbuffer, nat*3*8)
```

And this receiving code indeed gets a two dimensional arrays and so on. The same works in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to send an arbitrary object via `send`/`sendall` you will see an exception saying that a bytes-like is expected. So the idea is simple, numpy structures you send provide bytes-like interface, and conversion to bytes leaves just the raw binary data.

The easiest implementation is to inherit from `bytes`:

```
class A: pass
sock.sendall(A())  # exception

class B(bytes): pass
sock.sendall(B())  # no exception
```

However, numpy is a complex framework written in Python, Cython and C. They may use [C API](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/) to provide the similar functionality.

It's also worth noting that duck-typing doesn't work here as I would expect:

```
class C:
    def __bytes__(self):
        return bytes()

sock.sendall(C())  # exception
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean you expected that duck-typing would work or not? Also, I programmed a small sample python code where the receiver and sender is a python socket, and sent some numpy arrays. It worked, but the received data was not recovered, I got ▯▯ as value of the received data.

Comment: @Jadzia I expected duck-typing to work. As for your sample code, I think it's better to post another question if you're interested. It's possible that not everything in numpy can be send over a network "as is". It's also possible there's something incorrect in your send-receives, but I don't dare to insist on this because I don't see the code.

Comment: send/sendall expect a "bytes-like" object which is one that implements the buffer protocol API. Currently the buffer protocol can only be implemented in C. This is why you can send things like `array.array` and `numpy.array` and `memoryview` which do not inherit from `bytes`, but do implement the C API. There is an open ticket to allow pure python implementations of the buffer protocol, but it's low priority (having been open for nearly 5 years). https://bugs.python.org/issue13797

Comment: @Dunes and Vovanrock: Thanks for your replies, they were very helpful! 

In the mean time I also managed to send those numpy arrays from python to python and recover the data. This was possible with  the method np.fromstring(buffer, np.byte), which returns a proper numpy array again.

Comment: @Dunes: You mean send/sendall expect strings (according to the documentation), which are also bytes-like objects, right?

Comment: @Jadzia I believe you are referencing the python 2 documentation, where `str` is dual purpose. In python 3 `bytes` and `str` are separated out, and `str` is no longer bytes-like. Instead str can be converted to a bytes instance using the `encode` method.

Comment: @Dunes: Thanks for clarifying that. Yes, I was referring to Python 2.